# Metamask / Nano Ledger>

Tags: polkadot, error, wallet, metamask, ledger

**Metamask/ Nano Ledger: failed to execute requestDevide on HID. Must be handing a user gesture to show a permission request**

Hello, 2 years without problems, until yesterday I did: Reset Chrome settings. And after that the Metamask let it interact with the Ledger. I have HID enabled in both the wallet and Chrome, I also have the latest version of Metamask and Ledger.
The problem is with Chrome since using another PC everything works perfectly. Some help??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.